# Visual Studio 2022 .net 6 or 7 winform designer cannot generate event handler code automatically after renaming MainForm

Tags: winforms, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

I have a question while using Visual studio 2002 for winform .net 6 or 7

Visual Studio 2022 .net 6 or 7 winform designer cannot generate event handler code automatically after renaming "Form" to "MainForm".

I tried to double click winform designer mainform for generate "MainForm_Load" event handler code

But, The code is not generated and "MainForm.Designer.cs" is no code for that.

I cannot make sense for this situation.

But, In .net framework winform, this code is generated correctly.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Please let me know that if it's bug or has a solution for this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Regards.

Comment: The name of the delegate is not relevant, it may have a name that has nothing to do with the name of the Class, there's no reason to change it to something else; `SHIFT + F12` tells you which event it's handling -- You're supposed to override `OnLoad()` rather than subscribe to `Load` event in the same Form or UserControl